# Codeception, How to fill datepicker or press numbers

Tags: google-chrome, datepicker, codeception

I am writing little test and i have a problem with filling datepicker in chrome. I tried to use fillField but nothing.

Then I've used clickWithLeftButton and wait to show up the calendar, but i am not able to click in.

Next, I clicked in and tried to pressKey('CSS selektor',????), I can't find how to fill `01021997 - like date` , I can't use `"WebDriverKeys::..." because WebDriverKeys doesn't exist...`

Eventually sorry for my english. I hope you understand my problem.
Thanks a lot for answer.